# Android Threads Debugging

Tags: android, multithreading, java-native-interface

I have a huge code that upon user request starts new Activity with many JAVA threads and JNI pthreads. I am using adb shell top grep my_package and can see that not all threads are closed when the activity ends.
Is there a way to profile/monitor threads/process?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

I hope it well some one:
The process that I see with top and are remain when the activity is done are AsynchTask that the OS keep with thread pool.